# Invalid Conversion from 'int' to 'nodeType<int>'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linked-list, stack, dev-c++

I am trying to create a program that will reverse a linked list using a stack; however, I am continously getting the same error that I cannot set an node equal to an int yet I have seen multiple examples where this was possible! What could I be doing wrong?

Here is the code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;


#include "linkedStack.h"
nodeType<int> *head = NULL;
void traversal(linkedStackType<int>);

int main(){

    linkedStackType<int> Estack;
    linkedStackType<int> Ostack;
    linkedStackType<int> Tstack;
    Estack.initializeStack();
    Ostack.initializeStack();
    int num; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    cout << "Hello! Enter a number.\n";
    cin >> num;
        if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            cout << "This number is even! It's going to the even stack.\n";
            Estack.push(num);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "This number is odd! It's going to the odd stack.\n";
            Ostack.push(num);
        }
    }
    traversal(Estack);
    traversal(Ostack);

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
void traversal(linkedStackType<int> stack)
{
    nodeType<int> *current = NULL, *first = NULL;
        current = first;
        while (current != NULL) {
        stack.push(current->info);
        current = current->link;
    }
    while (stack.isEmptyStack() != true){
        current=stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        cout << current->info << " ";
    }
}
```

linkedStack.h

```
#ifndef H_StackType
#define H_StackType

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

#include "stackADT.h"

template <class Type>
struct nodeType
{
    Type info;
    nodeType<Type> *link;
};

template <class Type>
class linkedStackType :public stackADT<Type>
{
public:
    linkedStackType();

    //Default constructor
    //Postcondition: stackTop = NULL;

    Type top() const;

    //Function to return the top element of the stack.
    //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.
    //Postcondition: If the stack is empty, the program
    // terminates; otherwise, the top element of
    // the stack is returned.
    const linkedStackType<Type>& operator=
        (const linkedStackType<Type>&);
    //Overload the assignment operator.

    bool isEmptyStack() const;
    //Function to determine whether the stack is empty.
    //Postcondition: Returns true if the stack is empty;
    // otherwise returns false.

    bool isFullStack() const;

    //Function to determine whether the stack is full.
    //Postcondition: Returns false.

    void push(const Type& newItem);

    //Function to add newItem to the stack.
    //Precondition: The stack exists and is not full.
    //Postcondition: The stack is changed and newItem is
    // added to the top of the stack.

    void initializeStack();

    //Function to initialize the stack to an empty state.
    //Postcondition: The stack elements are removed;
    // stackTop = NULL;
    void pop();

    //Function to remove the top element of the stack.
    //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.
    //Postcondition: The stack is changed and the top
    // element is removed from the stack.

    linkedStackType(const linkedStackType<Type>& otherStack);
    //Copy constructor
    //~linkedStackType();

    //Destructor
    //Postcondition: All the elements of the stack are removed
private:

    nodeType<Type> *stackTop; //pointer to the stack

    void copyStack(const linkedStackType<Type>& otherStack);
    //Function to make a copy of otherStack.
    //Postcondition: A copy of otherStack is created and
    // assigned to this stack.
};


template <class Type>
linkedStackType<Type>::linkedStackType()
{
    stackTop = NULL;
}

template <class Type>
bool linkedStackType<Type>::isEmptyStack() const

{
    return(stackTop == NULL);
} //end isEmptyStack

template <class Type>
bool linkedStackType<Type>::isFullStack() const
{
    return false;
} //end isFullStack
template <class Type>

void linkedStackType<Type>::initializeStack()

{

    nodeType<Type> *temp; //pointer to delete the node
    while (stackTop != NULL) //while there are elements in
                             //the stack
    {
        temp = stackTop; //set temp to point to the
                         //current node
        stackTop = stackTop->link; //advance stackTop to the
                                   //next node
        delete temp; //deallocate memory occupied by temp
    }
} //end initializeStack

template <class Type>
void linkedStackType<Type>::push(const Type& newElement)
{
    nodeType<Type> *newNode; //pointer to create the new node
    newNode = new nodeType<Type>; //create the node
    newNode->info = newElement; //store newElement in the node
    newNode->link = stackTop; //insert newNode before stackTop
    stackTop = newNode; //set stackTop to point to the
                    //top node
} //end push
template <class Type>
void linkedStackType<Type>::pop()

{
    nodeType<Type> *temp; //pointer to deallocate memory
    if (stackTop != NULL)

    {
        temp = stackTop; //set temp to point to the top node
        stackTop = stackTop->link; //advance stackTop to the
                                   //next node
        delete temp; //delete the top node
    }
    else
        cout << "Cannot remove from an empty stack." << endl;
}//end pop

template <class Type>
Type linkedStackType<Type>::top() const
{
    assert(stackTop != NULL); //if stack is empty,
                              //terminate the program
    return stackTop->info; //return the top element
}//end top

template <class Type>
void linkedStackType<Type>::copyStack(const linkedStackType<Type>& otherStack)
{
    nodeType<Type> *newNode, *current, *last;
    if (stackTop != NULL) //if stack is nonempty, make it empty
        initializeStack();
    if (otherStack.stackTop == NULL)
        stackTop = NULL;
    else
    {
        current = otherStack.stackTop; //set current to point
                                       //to the stack to be copied
                                       //copy the stackTop element of the stack
        stackTop = new nodeType<Type>; //create the node
        stackTop->info = current->info; //copy the info
        stackTop->link = NULL; //set the link field to NULL
        last = stackTop; //set last to point to the node
        current = current->link; //set current to point to the
                                 //next node
            //copy the remaining stack

            while (current != NULL)

            {
                newNode = new nodeType<Type>;
                newNode->info = current->info;
                newNode->link = NULL;
                last->link = newNode;
                last = newNode;
                current = current->link;
            }//end while
    }//end else
} //end copyStack

template <class Type>
const linkedStackType<Type>& linkedStackType<Type>::operator=(const linkedStackType<Type>& otherStack)
{
    if (this != &otherStack) //avoid self-copy
        copyStack(otherStack);
    return *this;
}//end operator=
template <class Type>

linkedStackType<Type>::linkedStackType(const linkedStackType<Type>& otherStack)
{
    stackTop = NULL;
    copyStack(otherStack);
}//end copy constructor



#endif
```

stackADT.h

```
template <class Type>
class stackADT

{
public:

    virtual void initializeStack() = 0;

    //Method to initialize the stack to an empty state.

    //Postcondition: Stack is empty.

    virtual bool isEmptyStack() const = 0;

    //Function to determine whether the stack is empty.

    //Postcondition: Returns true if the stack is empty,

    // otherwise returns false.

    virtual bool isFullStack() const = 0;

    //Function to determine whether the stack is full.

    //Postcondition: Returns true if the stack is full,

    // otherwise returns false.

    virtual void push(const Type& newItem) = 0;

    //Function to add newItem to the stack.

    //Precondition: The stack exists and is not full.

    //Postcondition: The stack is changed and newItem is added

    // to the top of the stack.

    virtual Type top() const = 0;

    //Function to return the top element of the stack.

    //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.

    //Postcondition: If the stack is empty, the program

    // terminates; otherwise, the top element of the stack

    // is returned.

    virtual void pop() = 0;

    //Function to remove the top element of the stack.

    //Precondition: The stack exists and is not empty.

    //Postcondition: The stack is changed and the top element

    // is removed from the stack.

};
```

Exact error on visual studio:

a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "nodeType *"

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `Type top() const` returns `Type` (which in your case is `int`).  And `current=stack.top();` where `current` is `nodeType<int>*`, `current` isn't `int`, it's pointer-to`nodeType<int>`. So... error.  What is unclear about that ?

Comment: Off topic: in `void traversal(linkedStackType<int> stack)`, `linkedStackType<int> stack` would make more sense as a local variable than as a parameter.

Comment: "reverse a linked list using a stack" is not the same as "implement a stack as a linked list and print it in reverse". Which one is it you actually want to do?

Comment: Sorry for any inconsistencies; this is my first question. I would like to implement a stack as a linked list and print it in reverse so the output comes out in the FIFO format.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should change the `Type top() const;` into `nodeType<Type>* top() const;` in `"linkedStack.h"` and `"stackADT.h"`.And you should add `template <class Type>struct nodeType;` in the "stackADT.h" because `linkedStackType` derives from `stackADT`.Additionally, `Type top() const` should be modified as follows:

```
template <class Type>
nodeType<Type>* linkedStackType<Type>::top() const
{
    assert(stackTop != NULL); //if stack is empty,
                              //terminate the program
    return stackTop; //return the top element
}//end top
```

In this way, I compile the project successfully.

However, there is some algorithm problems in the function `void traversal(linkedStackType<int> stack)`. `current` and `first` both are NULL pointer.So what `current` point to when you `use current -> info`? I think you should modify this function `void traversal(linkedStackType<int> stack)`.